# Python - Optimizing Memory Usage in Calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I have a log file with about 50,000+ lines. Each line contains information pertaining to a worker and a job ID that a worker has "worked" on in a single day. For example,

```
 12:36:04.357 WorkerID: ABCD has worked on JobID: EFGH
```

Jobs do not disappear after being "worked on" and a worker might work on the same job multiple times. I need this program to quickly and efficiently:

1. Find how many unique JobIDs there are per WorkerID in a single log file
2. Find how many unique JobIDs there are per WorkerID per hour
3. Find the top 10 most worked on JobIDs per WorkerID in a single log file

Here's a bit of psuedocode I've written

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parselines(file):
    workDataHour = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
    workData = defaultdict(list)
    for line in file:
        hour = line[0:2]
        splitline = line.split()
        workID = splitline[2]
        jobID = splitline[7]
        workDataHour[workID][hour].add(jobID)
        workData[workID].append(jobID)

# Get 1) by len(Counter(workData[workID]))
# Get 2) by looping through each hour, and doing a len(workDataHour[workID][hour])
# Get 3) by Counter(workData[workID]).most_common(10)
```

Certainty this is fast but of course not memory efficient as there are two maps and workData contains a list of every workID in each line, essentially 50,000+ elements. Are there any data structures that would better suit my purposes? Any compression techniques for what I have so far? Something like optimizing my dict usage? Although this may be fine for now, I want to future proof the code for when I have to process 1,000,000+ lines.

Comment: you should investigate pandas for this

Comment: also, why are you worried about memory for 50000 elements? that is not a lot of data...

Comment: It's for when the app scales more and becomes bigger. It works fine for the amount of lines now but I want to future proof this.

Comment: You could also try [dask.array](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)

Comment: If you are saving to disk and concerned about memory usage why not write it in binary? Or you could write to something like hdf5 type, which does do compression as well. Fairly straightforward in python. I have found r/w operations with hdf5 to be extremely quick. Plus it gets you saved logs.